# Can I search for just (unanswered) content that matches my Interesting tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, search, unanswered-questions

I've answered questions in a lot of areas that are only of passing interest at best to me, so the 'my tags' feature when I go to look for Unanswered content is filled, frankly, with spam.

I may have one entry colored 'Interesting' for every few pages of noise.

I am able to set a list of Interesting tags in my preferences. Is there a way to get a list of questions (answered, unanswered, etc.) filtered to just those tags?

[Edit: As noted by Ritter below, I can Make a link like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell+monads . However, this doesn't extend to filtering that for unanswered content. Any ideas?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a bookmarklet that only shows your "Interesting" tags (make a bookmark, change the URL to the following):

```
javascript:void($(".question-summary%20+%20:not(.tagged-interesting)").hide())
```

Combined with the URL https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/haskell for example, it should do what you want..

It's not perfect, if there is only two interesting answers on the page, that's all you'll see at a time (anything else would have to be a server-side change..)

Answer (score 8):

The "my tags" part of unanswered now will use, *in this order*

1) Your Interesting tags

or, if you don't have any..

2) A sum of the top (n) tags in questions you've answered or asked

as before.

Comment: I realize a bookmark can fulfill most of this functionality, but it'd be really cool if users could specify what feed of questions (like unanswered question's I'm interested in) showed up when they visited the home page.  I hadn't even realized this page existed until now, but I'm pleased I finally found it.

Answer (score 2):

Make a bookmark of a search of your interesting tags.  [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security%20encryption%20cryptography).  You could use greasemonkey to put the link prominently on the SO page, or even generate it dynamically if you change your interesting links a lot.

Comment: Ah, that should work nicely.

Comment: Hrmm, but I can't seem to use that approach to filter for unanswered content that matches those tags.

Comment: IMHO a search of your interesting tags should be a prominent link on the standard site. It's too useful for everyone to have to add it themselves with greasemonkey.

Answer (score 1):

Click on tags, then click on the tag you want to search.  The page will then display only that tag's contents.

Any subsequent tags you click on on the left hand side will then be added to your search.