# List newest questions only matching my interesting tags?

Tags: feature-request, questions, search, my-tags

Is there a supported way of doing this?

Only seen this [hack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/can-i-search-for-just-unanswered-content-that-matches-my-interesting-tags) or this [workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21907/view-new-questions-marked-with-any-of-your-interesting-tags) which doesn't really do it for me.

Comment: I agree that this would be great - I have about 20 tags of interest, and yet most of the time, less than a quarter of the questions posted are ones I'd be interested in. I'm a PHP developer - I don't want to see (nor cannot answer) ASP.net questions (for example).

Answer (score 2):

So far there is no other way to achieve this. Interesting tags are used to color the questions on the client side in all question lists and to filter them in the unanswered my tags list. If you do not have interesting tags set, my tags will use the tags you answered to.

You can obviously also search for the tags using normal search in SO/SF/SU. If you have a long list of interesting tags, this gets tedious though.

There is a reason for this: SO/SF/SU and even meta want to encourage you to answer questions. Obviously you will do that in your field of interest most of the times, but you would miss many questions that you have a valid and great answer to outside of it. Even if it is only for somebody using the wrong tags.

If it were to easy to only see the newest questions in your field of interest, people would resort to that view as default and much would go unanswered.

Comment: @Ralph, good point at the end, but i find there's a lot of noise questions now that puts me off looking.  I'd widen my search to find more interesting tags now and then.

Comment: I totally disagree, I never really look at the latest questions because most are irrelavnt to me. I would answer far more if I could easily get a list that I could scan through.