# List Unanswered Questions in My Tags Sorted by Newest

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, sorting, my-tags

I found this related post:
[How to search for unanswered questions, in my tags only, newest first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64651/how-to-search-for-unanswered-questions-in-my-tags-only-newest-first)

But the work-around listed there doesn't work for me. The query uses the AND condition and returns only matches that include all of my tags instead of using the OR condition. See this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[ms-access]%20[access-vba]%20[ms-access-2007]%20answers%3a0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bms-access%5D%20%5Baccess-vba%5D%20%5Bms-access-2007%5D%20answers:0)

You can see another post related to this topic here: [List newest questions only matching my interesting tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23418/list-newest-questions-only-matching-my-interesting-tags)  In agreement with the comments there, there are simply far too many questions that are outside my scope of expertise.

Is there some good reason that this request isn't being considered?

Comment: I think mirabilos' edited solution to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64651/how-to-search-for-unanswered-questions-in-my-tags-only-newest-first answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

[You can use `OR` with tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/) and if you do that with your tags manually you get a URL like:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access OR access-vba OR ms-access-2007
```

[clickable here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access%20OR%20access-vba%20OR%20ms-access-2007)

From there you can click on the "Unanswered" tab, which sort of transmogrifies the URL a bit into this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access+or+access-vba+or+ms-access-2007?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50
```

[clickable here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access+or+access-vba+or+ms-access-2007?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50)

So basically, you can custom-craft searches for tags using the `/questions/tagged` URL and the `OR` operator, and then there are the tabs which are applied as arguments to help you get at least some of the otherwise searchable features like unanswered questions.

**edit**: this will not sort by newest as well, however, as you can only sort by one criteria at once using this method

Comment: OK, getting close. But how do i get all Unanswered sorted by Newest DESC?

Comment: So, in short, it can't be done.

Comment: @HK1 it would appear not, given the current implementation.  However as you've tagged this [feature-request] you may choose to incorporate the info above into your question and change it into a true feature request asking for this to *become* possible

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by adding a `sort:newest` option to search, as per [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160286/13295).

Answer (score 0):

Addind to @DanielDiPaolo's answer, if you want to see all unanswered that have two tags, use `AND` instead of `OR`, then you can choose for `newest`, `votes`etc...

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/regex+and+python?tab=newest
```