# Filter "MyTags" with no answers

Tags: feature-request, tags, filtering

Sorry if this sounds like a duplicate but i did not find what i was looking for through searching.

I've seen that you can filter every unanswered questions with "MyTags" like this is explained here : [View new questions marked with any of your 'interesting tags'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21907/view-new-questions-marked-with-any-of-your-interesting-tags)

I've also understood that when you click on a related tag, it is added in the search box with the **OR** operator like explained in the first answer here :  [Filtering questions by specifying multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/filtering-questions-by-specifying-multiple-tags)

But when i manually add tags, for instance [Excel] and [Python] in the search box, the page displays results like and **AND** operator (meaningly, displays posts which contains **both** tags).

What i intended to do was to have "MyTags" (like the first link showed) with no answers (i.e. as if i added *answers:0* in the search box) but i then understand that i want the search box to act like OR for tags but AND for answers which is unlogical.
Is there any other way to get this result ?

By the way, is there any way to sort Unanswered > MyTags by Newest ?
By default, they are sorted by "popularity" and i did not find a way to sort them any other way.

Thanks for your help,

Max

Comment: possible duplicate of [List Unanswered Questions in My Tags Sorted by Newest](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95763/list-unanswered-questions-in-my-tags-sorted-by-newest)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Eventually, i upvoted this feature request : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34001/is-there-a-way-to-sort-unanswered-my-tag-questions-by-date-newest-first