# Add sort option to search

Tags: feature-request, sorting, search, elasticsearch

There are a lot of feature requests based on sorting a set of questions, gathered by tabs or by searching, like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95763/13295).

How about we add a `sort:` option to the search box, for example `sort:newest` and then the answer set will be sorted accordingly?  Is this possible with the [new elasticsearch search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/13295) being implemented?

Comment: Can't you already do this by just clicking on the tabs?  Well, for *some* sorts, at least.

Comment: @Charles, the `newest` option works for some things, but you can't get two to happen at once.  So if you use the MyTags button, you can't sort by newest.

Comment: Oh, good point.

Comment: I don't think this would work the way you're envisioning, since the tags are **AND**-ed (always have been), hitting enter on that search box wouldn't yield results for most people with more than a few tags, *if* it did then you could still bookmark the search page of `answers:0` on the newest tab.

Comment: @Nick, can't you force an OR on the tags.  Of course, I think the real answer is to have a `favoritetags` option, that would search based on your favorite tags.  My prior feature request on that is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40117/add-advanced-search-option-to-search-within-a-users-interesting-favorite-ignore).

Comment: @Nick, wow if that was you who just downvoted that post, you were real quick.

Comment: @LanceRoberts - nope, but I know who did! dun dun dun! I need sleep.

Comment: @Nick, Have a Happy New Year!

Comment: @LanceRoberts - same to you! I'll take a look at the favorite tags thing but from some initial tests here the performance really isn't good for those who'd abuse it (having many tags, often including wildcards) exact string matches are one thing (tree on the heap is very efficient, etc.), partial compares are *much* worse.