# The Ability To Create Custom Question Filters Would Be Fantastic

Tags: feature-request, search, filtering

I really wish there were better ways to browse the questions on SO (and the like).  The Unanswered -> My Tags page is close to what I often want, but not always, and it often still gives me many questions I don't care about.

I'd like to be able to filter by (at least):

- Accepted/Unanswered/No Answers
- Tags to include, defaulting to
  letting the user select tags marked
  as interesting, but able to specify
  any tags
- Tags to exclude - starts with ignored tags, but again user selectable, this one's
  critical, and lacking from the
  current power-searches

I imagine a new button at the top, or maybe replacing 'Unanswered' called 'Custom' or 'Filters' - what's currently in 'Unanswered' could go inside this page - which would allow you to browse by pre-defined filters and by custom made filters, and also let you select which filter would be your default - what you see when you first hit SO.com.

The questions would be ordered like usual - in terms of last update - though I wouldn't be opposed to allowing other orderings, I don't see that as critical to this feature.

This would address several other requests/questions, including [search for unanswered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/can-i-search-for-just-unanswered-content-that-matches-my-interesting-tags), [view new interesting questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21907/view-new-questions-marked-with-any-of-your-interesting-tags), and [interesting questions tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions).  I realize the [power-user search tools](https://stackoverflow.com/search) provide a fair bit of this functionality, but non of the user friendly interface that I imagine.

This would be a huge boon for the usefulness of SO and would help prevent questions going unanswered and disappearing too quickly for those interested in answering to notice.  I believe the default view of the home page is crippling to the distributed knowledge of SO, and as the site grows it becomes imperative for power users to browse their own way.

Comment: Check this one out also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions

Comment: Thanks, included it in the post.

Answer (score 2):

> as the site grows it becomes imperative for power users to browse their own way.

I'd argue the power users already know how to browse by tag combinations.

Comment: Perhaps, but that's still limited.  I think integrating custom browsing patterns deeper into the UI would be very beneficial.  It's currently pretty easy for people to find a specific question, but I at least find myself sifting through many questions I wouldn't want to or be able to answer when I'm just looking to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

How about adding ability store latest search with a name?

1. Type what ever search criteria to search box and execute search
2. Click button "save latest search", give name to your search
3. Somewhere is a list of saved searches, where you can execute searches or delete them

Then again you could just bookmark searches in your browser.

Comment: bookmarking searches is simple and efficient but there's the issue of syncronising your bookmarks (between work and home).

Comment: Sure, bookmarks are fine - like I mention in the original post, power searches have most (but not all) of the functionality I'm looking for.  This is fundamentally a user interface request, not a backend feature request, as I believe browsing is an area where SO's user interface is severely lacking.