# Rank questions based on my important tags

Tags: feature-request

I need a feature - as I often find that I have do something that is ...

I have some interested tags, this sets the background to be different of the questions that I might find interesting. When I first get to SO, I end up quickly scrolling down the list to see if there is anything interesting.

Left feeling that is wasted time and annoying as you are "making me have to think"...

Could the most interesting questions to me (based on my interested tags) be at the top?

UPDATE

So I think of the homepage as

2 Sets

1. All Questions
2. Questions I have tagged as interesting

I am interested in both sets of questions - So I am not looking to reduce Set 1 by only showing Set 2.

I am looking for the intersection of Set 1 and Set 2 to be the first in the list.

This intersection is already known and used on the front page for highlighting.  Cant we use the intersection to simply rank too?

Answer (score 1):

There are some questions in this realm already, this [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested) for example asking for a tab that only shows questions with the user's interesting tags.

There also is a tab under `unanswered`: `my tags`. But it is limited to [unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11249/confusing-top-level-so-buttons-questions-and-unanswered/11250#11250) and sometimes based on the tags [I have answered question in previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/can-i-search-for-just-unanswered-content-that-matches-my-interesting-tags/7192#7192).

I always refrain from any ordering of questions by interest as I expect some interesting questions slipping by my attention. So I use a combination: I look at the question site on the  `active` tab and from time to time go to the `unanswered:my tags` tab. Or use [Jeff's advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60833/rank-questions-based-on-my-important-tags/60835#60835).

I find SE sites to be a great tool to learn about other areas of our profession and to think more cross-linked. I find myself answering a lot of questions in fields I would never go to.

Look at these posts too:

- [is there a way to display only questions from my interesting tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32392/is-there-a-way-to-display-only-questions-from-my-interesting-tags)
- [tab for interesting questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions)

Comment: Yes - i too like to see all the questions i am just saying that there seems to be, based on my behavior on the homepage, an inconsistency in that i choose interesting tags and they are highlighted but not at the top of the list ...  I now have to get an imperfect view of all the tags that I am interested in and tucked away in some dusty corner.

Answer (score 0):

You should be browsing just the tags you're interested in, then, and not wasting your time on the homepage.

See
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

Comment: I am just saying that there seems to be, based on my behavior on the homepage, an inconsistency in that i choose interesting tags and they are highlighted but not at the top of the list ...  I now have to get an imperfect view of all the tags that I am interested in and tucked away in some dusty corner.  You are also making me think and act when I dont want too.  - Either that or i choose not have interesting questions highlighted - which is a little crummy too - plus i like the homepage for all the other tags too.